# How to get the local area network shared devices and files?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

how to list the network shared devices over LAN from IPad.Is it possible to list the shared devices programmatically using objective-c ? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting the iPad to the network and what authentication is the network using? In general this would require a backend service to connect to the network and provide the network information over https to the iPad.

Comment: I am connecting my ipad through Wifi. How to access the shared folder of other users who connected to the same LAN or Wifi?

Comment: The iPad needs to understand the protocol or "language" of the other system. Out of the box it won't speak SMB (Windows Networking) but there are client applications that will do this. Are you looking to make a client app?

Comment: are you look at the image above? imac OS can fetch the Local shared devices. Likewise is it possible to list in ipad using Objective c ?

Comment: Aren't iOS applications sandboxed? I don't think its going to be as simple as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Using samba library we can access the LAN device files or using sockets with port of 445 can access the LAN machines.